# How to unset or clear a global variable in php YII2 Recursive function?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

On My Controller

```
   

 class BalanceSheetController extends Controller
{
    public $dataProvider=array(); //Global for The recursuive function
    public function recursive_select_transactions($ledger,$array_){
        
        $Current_ledger = AccountGroup::find()->where(['like','slug',$ledger])->one()->id;
            
        $get_childs = AccountGroup::find()->select('id,slug,parent_id,name')->where(['parent_id'=>$Current_ledger])->asArray()->all();
            
        if (count($get_childs) != 0) {
            
            foreach($get_childs as $childs ) {
                $this->recursive_select_transactions($childs['slug'],$array_);  
            }
        }
            
        $get_head = AccountHead::find()->where(['group_id'=>$Current_ledger])->asArray()->all();
            
        $get_head_altered=array();
        foreach($get_head as $head){
            $acc_slug = str_replace("-", "_", $head['slug']);
            $head['transaction_slug']=$acc_slug ;

            array_push($get_head_altered,$head);
        }
        foreach($get_head_altered as $key=>$val){
            $array_[]=$val['transaction_slug'];
        }
        $this->dataProvider[]=$array_;
    }
}
```

On My View

```
 

    function array_flatten($array)
    {
        if (!is_array($array)) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $result = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value));
            } else {
                $result[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    $liability = array();
    $liability_details = $this->context->recursive_select_transactions('liability', $liability);
    $liability_details = $this->context->dataProvider;
    $liability_slugs = array_flatten($liability_details);
    
    $asset=array();
    $asset_details = $this->context->recursive_select_transactions('asset', $asset);
    $asset_details = $this->context->dataProvider;
    $asset_slugs = array_flatten($asset_details);
    
    
    echo"<pre>";print_r($liability_slugs);echo"<pre>";
    echo"<pre>";print_r($asset_slugs);echo"<pre>";
```

$dataProvider is the global variable.And The Resultant array,The last called have the elements of first Called.Cause the global Variable keeps

```
Array
(
    [0] => chitty_settlement
    [1] => cess_collected
    [2] => hallmarking_charges_received
    
)
Array
(
    [0] => chitty_settlement
    [1] => cess_collected
    [2] => hallmarking_charges_received
    [3] => output_cgst_ac
    [4] => output_igst_ac
    [5] => output_sgst_ac
   
)
```

This first Array (**libility**) element remains when it called with diiferent **parameter** (**asset**).
How To Clear the Elements of Global Variable before its again called with different Parameter
I tried this

```
 $liability = array();
    $liability_details = $this->context->recursive_select_transactions('liability', $liability);
    $liability_details = $this->context->dataProvider;
    $liability_slugs = array_flatten($liability_details);

    unset($this->context->dataProvider);

    $asset=array();
    $asset_details = $this->context->recursive_select_transactions('asset', $asset);
    $asset_details = $this->context->dataProvider;
    $asset_slugs = array_flatten($asset_details);
```

its not working.

Comment: I don't see any global variable ,, try explain better which is the global variable and update your question and add  also the data sample not only the result  ..

Answer (score 0):

$this->context->dataProvider=array();